# How to set timeout for yield call in React Redux-Saga

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

In my rest API backend I do heavy processing and usually, it takes 1.5 minutes to produce a result, in that time I'm getting this error in my frontend react application.

```
Error: timeout of 60000ms exceeded
```

So, peer connection is lost.

How do I set request timeout in redux-saga

Comment: This could be happening for a number of reasons and you haven't given any detail on how your app is set up. Have you checked your webserver/proxy for timeout limits? Are there timeout limits on the frontend ajax calls being made by react?

Answer (score 10):

i was used [`race`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RacingEffects.html) for such things. May be it will useful for you.

```
  const {posts, timeout} = yield race({
    posts: call(fetchApi, '/posts'),
    timeout: delay(60 * 1000)
  });
  if (timeout) throw new Error('timeout of 60000ms exceeded')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { eventChannel, END } from 'redux-saga'

function countdown(secs) {
  return eventChannel(emitter => {
      const iv = setInterval(() => {
        secs -= 1
        if (secs > 0) {
          emitter(secs)
        } else {
          // this causes the channel to close
          emitter(END)
        }
      }, 1000);
      // The subscriber must return an unsubscribe function
      return () => {
        clearInterval(iv)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
export function* create(action) {
  try {
    const { payload } = action;
    const response = yield call(api.addPost, payload);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log('pass 200 check');
      yield put(appActions.setResourceResponse(response.data));
      console.log(response.data);
      payload.push('/add-news');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    yield put(
      a.setResponse({
        message: error.response.data,
        status: error.response.status,
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the timeout occurs during the API call from django rest API